# Problem with the Mortarboard badge?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, reputation, badges

I had got a reputation of 225 (200+) on a day, but wasn't awarded the Mortarboard badge.

So, just wanted to know whether the badge is still active or is the explanation of the badge wrong; so that it doesn't create confusion in the future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Association bonuses (and bounties, had you had any) don't count toward the total. It comes from upvotes (+10 per answer vote, +5 per question), accepted answers (+15), and the odd +2's you get for stuff like suggested edits being accepted (eventually they don't count any more either), <strike>and accepting an answer yourself</strike>. (turns out I was wrong about that last one.)

They're not easy to get. Three decent answers and a couple of acceptances will get you close, but it helps if you have some carry-over upvotes from an answer or two the previous day (people upvoting the next day).

[If you pass 200 but then spend points (say setting up a bounty), you can lose your "passed 200 in a day" as well. I've been caught by that one a bunch of times.]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I had an association bonus that day. So, that counts to 125 on that day.

A real neat explanation like this one is definitely needed, in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: One of the answers on the "[FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) for stackexchange sites" has the details (they can be found in a few other places as well.) See the third bullet point under "Additionally" [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).